# Read a .rad file using matlab (textscan without first lines)

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'd like to read into matlab my .rad file which is like that :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w057nsnvquzrc18/RAD.rad?dl=0

I tried to use `textscan` and this :

```
D = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',' ','headerlines', 19);
```

I got this :

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've specified that the delimiter is a comma, and are confused why the data is being split at the commas? Specify the delimiter as a space instead...

Comment: Thanks! ..but it does not work, I got an error : Dimensions of matrices being
concatenated are not consistent. So If I remove the cell2mat, it's a bit better but I get NaN value if each column... @Wolfie

Comment: **1.** Please edit your question to include an actual excerpt from the file, instead of an image, so we can copy and paste it to run your code ourselves. **2.** I have no idea what the output looks like before or after you took my advice, because you haven't shown us. Edit your question to include the outputs you're getting as well as what your *expected* output is.

Comment: You should add the text of your file here (minimal text required to reproduce the problem) instead of referring to external links.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- reading the numerical data as "string"
- replace the "comma" with a "dot"
- convert the cellarray to a char array
- convert the string to number with the function str2num

a possible implementatino could be:

```
fid=fopen('RAD.rad','r')
% Read the data as strings
x=(textscan(fid, '%s', 'headerlines', 19))

% Remove the last row (string: END OF FILE)
x{1}(end-2:end)=[];

fclose (fid)

% Define the number of variables
n_vars=5
% Get the number of data
n_data=length(x{1})
% Identify the number of rows
n_rows=n_data/n_vars
data=str2double(strrep(x{1},',','.'));
the_data=reshape(data,n_vars,n_rows)'
```

**Edit following the comments of the OP**

I've tested the code with the file you've posted.

I've updated the code to discard the last line of the input (since it is the string "END OF FILE").

The `x` variable is `{11550x1 cell}` so the data are stored in `x{1}`.

The second part of the code, generate the matrix `the_data` which contains the datra read from the inout file.

```
>> whos the_data
  Name             Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  the_data      2310x5             92400  double
```

Comment: `str2num` uses `eval` within it. Use `str2double` instead.

Comment: Helps a lot. Thanks. In x I got 5 cell and in each one I have my column 1 by 1. So it's quiet nice, I could use it! Thank you very much. It could be better if I could have my data in a whole matrix, but I can work with those data. In data I got NaN so the reshape does not work ! Thanks

Comment: I've updated the code, you have to discard the last line of your input file.

Comment: @SardarUsama thanks for the suggestion, I've upodated the code.